# Windows service doesn't hit OnStart unless using Administrator account

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, privileges

The service installs correctly but when attempting to start it via `net start` or from the services window it doesn't start at all, not even getting to the `OnStart` handler.

If I use an administrator account, the service starts and works correctly.  This seems to suggest something in the service requires admin privileges but this is purely an on-demand style service with nothing executing until requested.  With this type of service I'd assume that is should at least start and then fail later when a request is made to it that requires admin privileges?

It's impossible to debug as I can't even get it to start and nothing is appearing on the event logs apart from an Information log stating that the service stopped.  There's too much code in the service to add it all here but the entry point is a fairly standard Unity style service:

```
partial class MyServiceHost : UnityServiceBase
{
    private Bootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    public MyServiceHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart( string[] args )
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter( "ServiceTestLog.txt" );
        tw.Write( "Date: " + DateTime.Now + "\n" );

        try
        {
            base.OnStart( args );

            _bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper( UnityContainer );
            _bootstrapper.Run();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            tw.Write( ex.ToString() );
        }

        tw.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _bootstrapper.Teardown();
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

For business reasons I can't just make the user account it uses an administrator so I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

Comment: See Steve Townsend's answer, but why does it need to be a service?  What does it do that it can't do running as a normal detached process?

Comment: @CareyGregory This is just a small part of the whole service oriented architecture of our code base.  Rather than include all the details of why it must be a service I'll just say that I have no choice in that matter!

Comment: Run sysinternals processmonitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see what's failing. It may be getting "access denied" on required dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to "ServiceTestLog.txt" may require local admin rights.

Comment: That could be a secondary issue down the road, but note that execution does not even reach `OnStart` yet per the q text

Comment: It depends on how the OP has determined that it does not reach OnStart.

Comment: The first thing I tried was to comment out writing to the log and it didn't work.  However, I tried it again this time actually uninstalling and re-installing the service and it worked!  How embarrassing but thank you for pointing this out and making me try again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your user account has the "Log on as a Service" privilege.  This won't work without that, and it's not on by default for users, though it would be for administrator.  Instructions [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/a6fcbe72-6f75-4bd2-bb96-440e2c8913c2).

Comment: Log on as a service is enabled for the account yet it's still not working unfortunately

Comment: Not sure how well this works for managed code, but ProcessDumper can produce a postmortem debuggable dump on process exit.  It might give you a hint on where the failing service is exiting from.  Incrementally adding diagnostic output until you narrow down where the failure is should be useful now and later.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I wasn't aware of ProcessDumper that will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Visual Studio Debugger and attach to the service and you can step through it and see what's going on.

You can add this before initializecomponent() and add WAITFORDEBUGGER in the Service Control Panel "Start parameters" textbox for your service.

C#:

```
foreach (string arg in args) {
    if (arg == "WAITFORDEBUGGER") {
        while (!Debugger.IsAttached) {
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

VB.Net:

```
For Each arg As String In args
   If arg = "WAITFORDEBUGGER" Then
       While Not Debugger.IsAttached
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
       End While
   End If
Next
```

The service will then wait for you to fire up Visual Studio and attach the debugger, at which point you can trace through the entire initialization and run sequence and see what's broken.

If it never hits the WAITFORDEBUGGER code, it's probably having trouble loading a dependency, in which case Sysinternals Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can tell you what it's getting hosed on.